# Where does Junkrat's RIP-Tire name come from?

Tags: overwatch

I assume it's a pun but I'm not a native speaker and I don't get why it's named like that.

- Is it RIP as in "rest in peace"?
- Is it a pun on "riptide"? (Considering he's Australian. afaik that word seems important in Australian culture)
- Does "rip" just have its literal sense, "to tear", like a tire that rips things apart?

Or is it not clear even for native speakers?

<sub>I think it's something you get if you're a native speaker so I thought about posting in on ell but I figured it's more on-topic here.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a pun on both "rip tide" and "ripcord", the cord pulled the start the tire, with "RIP" being capitalized as in "rest in peace".

Answer (score 3):

I'd disagree with the other answer and suggest it's a pun on 'rip-cord', the cord you pull to open the parachute, or I've known it as the cord you pull to start a (for example) lawnmower motor (though I can't find any references to that online). Wikipedia also suggests it's the term for the thing you pull to start a Beyblade spinning. Given that Junkrat pulls some kind of cord to start the RIP-Tire like he's starting a motor it seems to reference one of the above.

Comment: Yeah, after looking it up I'm not convinced that "rip cord" is the pun they were going for. It seems to be used only for parachutes or beyblades (for lawn mowers it's just "cord"), so it's unlikely they kept only the "rip" part of the word that has no reference online at all.